# App runs inside Teams, but not on localhost

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and docs are unclear. I have used the MS Teams Toolkit for VSCode to generate the project. My ngrok tunnels are up and I can run my tabs and bot inside the Teams Client after adding the Development.zip file.

I have simple tabs, but now I need to call APIs, debug stuff, log info and actually see it, etc.
I've put a simple console.log() in my code to test it out...

The terminal for the tabs, launching react, gives me this:

[image]

but when I go to localhost:3000/search (search is my tab name), I get this...

[image]

I did go back to the client, opened the DevTools, looked at the console... no console.log

I've also tried to add a certificate as mentionned in the docs, but when I go to https//localhost:3000 the Certificate options they mentionned arent visible.

You'd think an extension by Microsoft for Microsoft would work out of the box and be well documented... Oh man. I need to be able to debug this, interact with the bot, etc. just as you'd do with a standard React app...

Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please me understand which sample code have you picked to create this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Web Client instead. Easy access to your console from there and opens just fine.